# Why can not log in stack exchange

Tags: discussion, login

I am come from China, and I can't log in stack exchange. It is always show 'requires external javascript from another domain' when I click log in.

Comment: I am sorry, but I posted this question as a tourist.

Comment: (I think you are missing part of your last comment because the sentence ends with "And"??) I don't know what you mean by "tourist". If you mean something like "outsider" or "foreigner" then please don't feel that way. This site is user-generated and community-moderated. EVERYBODY who contributes usefully and respectfully is welcome.

Comment: Sorry for my question. Pls delete it.And Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Is this still a problem? Can you log in now?