# Comment, edit post on meta with 1 rep?

Tags: support, comments, meta

[This question](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3443/33055) got migrated from the main site.

The user has been asked for clarification in comments, but that user has only 1 rep. Can such a user answer, or update her/his post, if (s)he hasn't got the minimum of 5 rep necessary to [participate in meta](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta)? Or can you always edit your own posts, even on meta with too little rep?¹

As that user has not other questions, it is impossible to "upgrade" the user by up-voting such a question (up-voting on meta has no effect on rep).

If I had realised this before, and up-voted the question before voting to move, would the rep have been lost by the move to meta?²

In principle this could also happen if a user a very few questions and answers and low rep, then posts on meta and her/his rep decreases by a down-vote or a changed/retracted vote. But then at least one can bump the less-than-5-rep, by up-voting one of the questions/answers on main.

¹ <sub>A move to another site would not be the problem, that should work as there is no minimum rep to participate, you just have to add that site to your account.</sub>
² <sub>Probably it is, I am just curious in case up-voting before voting to move, would help for a future occurrence</sub>

Comment: I can confirm that Braiam is correct. I tried this using a (shh!) sockpuppet account, asked a bogus question, migrated it to meta and could indeed edit it.

Comment: Don't upvote a post to give a user a privilege. That's the one rule of voting: vote on the post, not on the user.

Comment: @gilles Acknowledged. I was only considering doing so if, and only if, the user would not be able to modify the post after the move (to temporarily work around what I would consider a bug, until that bug would be fixed, or indicated by design)

Comment: @terdon thanks for confirming. I suspected this would work, but just wanted to be sure.

Comment: @terdon BTW your comment never showed up in my recent Inbox messages. In only did see it because I looked at Gilles comment.

Comment: That's strange. If this one doesn't either, we should let SE know.

Comment: @terdon this one showed up, maybe just a glitch, I was online the whole time though.

Comment: WRT "upgrade voting", I don't think there's anything wrong with exploiting a system to circumvent parts of that system you consider broken, Anthon -- *that's a hack*.  The "can't comment, can answer" and related issues are NOT considered bugs, and hence will never be fixed -- but if you think it is stupid/wrong (**it often is**) in certain circumstances, work around it.   The archetypal S.E. power user stance that the system is perfect, we just need to understand why it is this way is can get absurdly trite. $0.02

Comment: To elaborate further contra @Gilles  *[that's a hack](https://stallman.org/articles/on-hacking.html)*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Users can independently of reputation edit and comment on their own posts. This works in meta the same as the main site.